# apache commons| pool or pool2

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons, apache-commons-dbcp

I was just trying to use DataSource from apache commons-dbcp.jar. For that I just downloaded one of their example. So far so good. Example stand as 
([this](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/dbcp/trunk/doc/PoolingDataSourceExample.java?view=markup))

```
// Here are the dbcp-specific classes.
 // Note that they are only used in the setupDataSource
// method. In normal use, your classes interact
// only with the standard JDBC API
//
  import org.apache.commons.pool2.ObjectPool;
  import org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool;
  import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.ConnectionFactory;
  import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource;
  import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory;
  import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverManagerConnectionFactory;
```

Nothing is wrong in that except for instead of importing from

```
     import org.apache.commons.pool
```

they have imported from

```
     import org.apache.commons.pool2
```

Well, it took me minutes,adding and readding the required jar, before I could figure out they have actually imported different package name from what they have provided in jar.

Well, I'm still puzzled, is it just a mistake or some intentional mysterious reason(in which case I'll like to know and that is the question).

Expert comment from apache-commons please?

Answer (score 2):

Both DBCP and Pool have released 2.x versions. Since there were compatibility breaks in the 2.x versions, the package names were changed.  Changing the package names allows 1.x and 2.x versions to coexist on the classpath.  Users are encouraged to upgrade to the latest 2.x versions.

Answer (score 1):

The apache commons team is working on a 2.0 release. More information can be found on the road map:  http://wiki.apache.org/commons/PoolRoadMap .